# O uso de muitas variáveis no CSS pode afetar o desempenho da página?

Tags: css, css3, variáveis

O uso de muitas variáveis no CSS, pode acabar degradando muito a performance da página?

É possível dizer mais ou menos o uso de quantas seriam necessárias pra começar a trazer um impacto negativo?

Um exemplo de variável:

```css
html {
  --example: white;
}

p {
  color: var(--example);
}
```

Comment: Ao que exatamente você se refere quando diz `variáveis`?

Comment: @MagicHat Obrigado, atualizei minha resposta.

Comment: Cara eu já li algumas coisas sobre CSS variables, e nunca vi nada relacionado a performance, mas o que vc pode levar em consideração, caso esteja fazendo um framework por exemplo, é que `color: var(--example);` tem alguns caracteres a mais que `color: red;` e isso pode aumentar os `KBs` do seu `.CSS`. Lógico que é um exemplo para casos extremos com um .CSS com mais de 10mil linhas etc... Talvez com um PostCSS ou Webpacker vc consiga configurar o output dessas variáveis

Answer (score 1):

Vou dividir a resposta em duas parte, vamos lá

**Primeira:**

Sim pode e muito. A performance pode variar entre varios fatores,

- Relacionar o item;
- Quantidade de filhos que uma variavel atende;
- Se ela é usada em uma div que contem 10000 outras div;
- Se ela só possui um filho;

Incluir JS nessa equação vai gerar ainda mais delay no tempo de renderização.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Segunda:**

A quantidade não importa tanto, mas sim onde vai ser usada e quanto elemento ela afeta, uma boa pratica seria definir variaveis para pontos chaves como textos alterando tamanho e fontes.

Caso seu objetivo for mesmo a performance você pode usar pré processadores de CSS simples e "leves" como **STYLUS**.

**Referencias:**

https://blog.jiayihu.net/css-custom-properties-performance-in-2018/

https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/getting-started-stylus

Comment: Cara pre-processado de CSS não resolve nada, uma vez que o output dele vai continuar sendo um .CSS gigante só que piorado, pois ele vai trocar o que era uma variável, por um valor fixo, dificultando ainda mais as coisas...

Comment: A pergunta foi referente a performance de  variaveis em css, o arquivo "compilado do css" vai ter uma performance melhor por não usar elas.

Comment: Claro, o arquivo compilado não vai ser legivel mas não é bem o foco dele.

Comment: Eu estava até repetindo os testes do link aqui, achei bem inconclusivo, talvez precise de um ambiente mais adequado para testar, mas comparado aos testes dele de 2018, no Chrome / iOS, com um arquivo de 25mil linhas, achei difícil afirmar algo, até pq só com esse senário, rodando localmente, a variação foi na casa de 400ms de diferente, algo quase imperceptível visualmente para o usuário

Comment: A minha finalidade é realmente saber se usar muito elas no CSS pode degradar muito a performance, ou se eu poderia usar despreocupado porque não teria muito impacto. Então deixa ver se eu entendi, a quantidade que eu utilizar delas não importa? O que pode impactar é usando elas em filhos, por exemplo?

Comment: Sim, a quantidade em si não tem tanto inpacto, oque mais gera é onde ela é usada